# Reorder mysql results based off of html <select> choice?

Tags: php, html, mysql

another possibly dumb question... I have a database for reviews on items from a webpage. I also have the reviews populating a table on my page based off of the mysql tables data.

What i want to do, and I've searched online but not managed to find a solution, is to reorder the code based upon the selection made on my html dropdown menu.

Any advice?

The code as it stands. If any more is required I can provide it.

```
    <p>Order By: <select>
  <option value="newest" id="newest">Newest First</option>
  <option value="oldest" id="oldest">Oldest First</option>
  <option value="highest" id="highest">Highest Rating</option>
  <option value="lowest" id="lowest">Lowest Rating</option>
</select></p>

<?php
include "common.php";

mysql_connect("HOST", "USER", "PASS") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("DB") or die(mysql_error());
 $sql = "SELECT email, review, rating FROM reviews ORDER BY review_id DESC ";
  $result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

  echo "<table>";
  echo "<tr><th>User</th><th>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</th><th>Review</th><th>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</th><th>Rating</th></tr>";

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $email     = $row['email'];
    $review    = $row['review'];
    $rating    = $row['rating'];

echo "<tr>
  <td>".$email."</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>".$review."</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>".$rating."</td>
  </tr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: This is a fairly basic concept - all you need to do is to take the value in your drop-down and use it in your SELECT statement's ORDER By clause.

Comment: Yeah I knew it would be... reckon I'm overthinking everything too much.

Comment: Please be aware that the mysql extension (supplying the `mysql_` functions) has been deprecated since 2012, in favor of the mysqli and PDO extensions. It's use is highly discouraged. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p>Order By: 
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?> method="GET">
    <select name="ordering">
      <option value="pk DESC" id="newest">Newest First</option>
      <option value="pk ASC" id="oldest">Oldest First</option>
      <option value="rating DESC" id="highest">Highest Rating</option>
      <option value="rating ASC" id="lowest">Lowest Rating</option>
    </select>
</form>
</p>

<?php
include "common.php";

mysql_connect("HOST", "USER", "PASS") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("DB") or die(mysql_error());
if(isset($POST['ordering'])) { 
    $sql = "SELECT email, review, rating FROM reviews ORDER BY" . $POST['ordering'];
} else {
     $sql = "SELECT email, review, rating FROM reviews ORDER BY review_id DESC ";
}
 $result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

  echo "<table>";
  echo "<tr><th>User</th><th>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</th><th>Review</th><th>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</th><th>Rating</th></tr>";

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $email     = $row['email'];
    $review    = $row['review'];
    $rating    = $row['rating'];

echo "<tr>
  <td>".$email."</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>".$review."</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>".$rating."</td>
  </tr>";
}
?>
```

All you need to do is wrap the `select` in a `form` that submits to itself, change the `option` values to partial SQL queries, and finally make a conditional SQL statement based off of the form input.

Comment: Fixed it. Thank you! Not sure why I hadnt thought of it before... but it works!

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the selected value to the php in some way:
- by POST or GET, submitting a form or trough ajax

Then you need to order by according to that value, and return the result to the screen.

I assume you are new to PHP, so I'd recommend you to read about PDO, mysqli, or some other framework to connect to database, because mysql_* functions are deprecated, and to properly sanitize your string before putting it on the query.